# "You have too many pending edits"

Tags: discussion, editing, suggested-edits

I know what this means, but it has been like that for about 24 hours. Only once one of my edits was acknowledged, and then this message again. Are there *so many* pending edits that people are not being able to check them?

Comment: I just approved a number of your edits, but I think it takes 3 people for the edits to be final. 

Comment: @ArturMeinild it takes two to 'approve' or two to 'reject', or one to 'improve' or one 'reject and edit'. If there are 3 reviewers it means there was disagreement.

Comment: @Zanna thanks for clearing that up 

Comment: Thanks @ArturMeinild & Zanna

Comment: I also approved one of your edits today to an answer I posted to a question yesterday. It didn't take long for it to be applied and thanks for your formatting input 

Comment: Thank you @graham

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry about that. Suggested edits to be reviewed used to show up much more prominently in the top bar. *Grumble grumble, back in my day, etc etc*. We keep having this problem. I'm not sure how to solve it. Please do become a prolific reviewer of Suggested Edits once you earn the privilege ;)

By the way...

[image: Suggested edit review page example]

I rejected that. Please don't remove the link text entirely. Keep it as alt text if it is not needed or replace it with something more informative. Also make images links with this syntax:

```
[![alt text here][1]][1]
```

Answer (score 3):

I completely agree with [@Zanna's answer](https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/20490/618353) and rejection reason for your edit (I also [rejected the edit](https://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/1344807) for the same reason).

I would like to make clear, though, that the reason why you got the message *"You have too many pending edits"* is not that the [*Suggested edits* review queue](https://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits) is full. It's almost empty right now actually and in quite good shape in terms of edits waiting for review.

The real reason that you got the message is because a user with less than 2000 rep (i.e. without [editing privileges](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/edit)) can only suggest up to 5 edits at any given time. So, if you have 5 edits pending review and try to suggest another one, you will get the message. If then one of your suggested edits gets reviewed, you will be able to suggest another edit, but if you try to suggest one more you will get the same message again, because your pending edits are already 5. In other words, it's like a personal queue, unrelated to the number of posts waiting for review in the *Suggested edits* queue.

Finally, keep in mind that the reason for some delays in reviews of suggested edits can be attributed to the time difference, which is of course related to the fact that not many people participate in the review queues.